# loosing scope of the request params in async for firestore document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying firestore first time with express. I have this code

```
app.post('/api/create', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
          console.log(req.body);
          //the above consle.log shows the following
          // { 'id': 'HYHDHHD9', 'item': 'name'  }   
          await db.collection('items').doc('/'+req.body.id+'/')
              .create({item: req.body.item});
              // req.body.id is undefined in the db.collection..why??
    
    
          return res.status(200).send();
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
     
        }
      })();
  });

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The issue is that if I hard code req.body.id below
`await db.collection('items').doc('/'+req.body.id+'/') .create({item: req.body.item});`
like this
`await db.collection('items').doc('testdocument') .create({item: req.body.item});`
then it works fine as it does not have to get the req.body but when I use just (notice using req.body variable)
`await db.collection('items').doc('/'+req.body.id+'/') .create({item: req.body.item});`
then it shows undefined for req.boady.id and req.body.item

Only explanation I have is that somehow I am loosing the context (scope) of req in there. How can I make sure that it passes through?

console.log shows that api passes the parameters id and item just fine in the request. req.body.id and req.body.item are just not available in this context
`**await db.collection('items').doc('/'+req.body.id+'/').create({item: req.body.item});**`
`
**** some mroe info **
req.body is available before and after the db.collection call.
Its just undefined in the db.collection call as it creates an undefined collection name. Thats how I know that it is picking it up as undefined**

Below are some screenshots that have comments of console.log

[image]

******************* LATEST EDIT **************
Ok did some more debugging
I get req.body
but I cant get the parameter id in req.body. So req.body.id is undefined right after req.body
checkout in the screenshot with debugging comments
[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out the code that isn't working the way you expect.  I think it will be easier if you put the code from your description into the actual code sample, along with logging, and use comments to explain better what's not working, so we can see everything in context.

Comment: I have the actual code there. There is not much of logging involved. I think I am loosing the scope for req

Comment: req doesn't change at all as you go into your function, and doesn't escape the scope.  What is the log output that's different than what you expect?  If you add more logging and explain the output of each line, that will help illustrate.

Comment: does not still work. When I send the request from api, req.body.id and request.body.item is undefined. funny thing is that console.log picks it up properly if I console.log them out right before the call db.collection('items',req).doc('/'+ req.body,id +'/') .create({item: req.body.item});

Comment: I suggest showing minimal code examples that both work and do not work, so we can see more clearly what the difference is.  Your description is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: "*console.log shows that api passes the parameters id and item just fine in the request*" - would you like to edit the question to show the exact log output, so we can see for ourselves?  All we see now is "console.log(req.body)".  It would also help to see the code that makes the request.  We just can't see what data you're working with here.

Comment: I am not sure how else to explain that in more details. In code its clearly there right after try. I am saying that I know request parameters gets passed as I have console.log there and it shows that values are coming in. Its just those values are undefined when I call then in await db.collection......

Comment: Show us how you know - provide the log output at every stage that proves what's actually going on.

Comment: edited to best of my ability

Comment: Now, add the following log line before and after the call to Firestore.  What does it show?  `console.log(req.body.id)`

Comment: thats the issue as I said. Its undefined in the db.collection call but besides that its available before and after that call

Comment: If you're saying that a log of `req.body.id` **by itself** shows undefined immediately after a log of `req.body` that shows an id property, that is difficult to believe.

Comment: No I did not say that. I said that it is NOT undefined .... before and after of db.collection call. Its just undefined in the db.collection call as it creates an undefined collection name. Thats how I know that it is picking it up as undefined

Comment: When it completes it creates an undefined document name, that tells me that its taking its scope as undefined

Comment: I suggest showing a screenshot of your observations so we can all agree what actually happened.  **Again, we need to be able to see what you see.**

Comment: added if that helps

Comment: You really should have had that error message in the question from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Ok there are few things I needed to do to get this working.

```
1- I needed to add 
app.use(express.urlencoded());
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
2- I needed to make sure that I an sending a request via x-www-form-urlencoded.
```

That did the magic.

Comment: In "request.body", the "body" object is added by the body-parser middleware. In order to load the middleware, you do that... app.use(...). And yes, that's the way body-parser works tho. If you don't tell app to use certain middleware, you wont be able to use it.

Comment: yea I guess I was missing that bit of info tip

Answer (score 0):

The code in your screenshot doesn't match what you copied into your question.  You actually have:

```
await db.collection('items').doc('/'+req.body,id+'/')
```

Note that there is a comma between "body" and "id".  The error message is telling you that a variable named `id` is undefined.

The slashes are not going to be useful here, so your code should actually just be:

```
await db.collection('items').doc(req.body.id)
```

Make sure you have a period between "body" and "id".

Comment: that is not it. Was a type. but it was not it. Please check the update. I found out that req.body is defined however req.body.id is not accessible ...not sure why

Comment: Now I'm utterly confused because you assured me in comments that it was "NOT undefined".  I don't think there's anything I can do to help at this point.

Comment: The json object was there in req but I just could not access its property. Its ok. thanks for trying. I think I will figure it out after a few more debugs :)